# Auto populate Share On Your Newsfeed Text

Tags: 2013, javascript, newsfeed

I have a requirement i want to auto-populate the text in the "`Share on Your Newsfeed`" textbox with some dynamic text. 
The background is we have a quiz and at the end of that we want user to share that on their newsfeed just like Facebook. We need a popup like below when we click on a button:

[image]

Comment: $('#ms-microbloginputbox').val('text here'); should work. Create a page with a newsfeed webpart. you can only show the textbox area using css. pass your dynamic string as parameter. read that string using "JSRequest"   object or GetUrlKeyValue methods. execute $('#ms-microbloginputbox').val('text here'); inside _spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(function(){$('#ms-microbloginputbox').val('pass dynamic text here');})

Answer (score 2):

You can call below url in your Sp.UI.ModalDialog to open a popup with your custom message prefilled:

```
<SiteURL>/<NewsFeedSite>?ArticleUrl=YourCustomText
```

Main Query string paramenter is **ArticleUrl=YourCustomText**